# Is cron the best way of writing reminder based application in php?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Suppose I have a database like this.

```
| task                      |  time                     | 
|---------------------------|---------------------------| 
| Remind me to water plants |  2018-02-18T19:32:10.486Z | 
| English Test              |  2018-10-8T09:30:00.000Z  | 
| Math Test                 |  2018-10-8T10:30:00.000Z  |
```

And I want to send a reminder notification to the user at the time it has been requested (or maybe an hour before) by the user and also execute some other block of code at that specific time when reminder notification is triggered.

I am thinking of writing a cron job something like this

`* * * * * php /laravel-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

as mentioned in laravel documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling).

And inside that script, I will be looping onto current time reminders and reminders within next hour and perform actions.

Is it a good practice? Won't it increase traffic between PHP and database? What if i have lot of reminders within the same hour, looping into that and executing blocks of code foreach reminder will be it a good idea?

Please suggest ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) is the correct way to go about this. If you have a large number of reminders to process then setting them up to execute as [queued jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues) is the recommended approach. That way the load on the server is minimized and does't bottleneck the system for user traffic.

You'll probably want to create a [console command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) to handle the processing logic and create the jobs. [Chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#chunking-results) the jobs will also be helpful, as that will stagger out the number of jobs processed in a given batch.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I have the same question for a SMS (Text) message system and I choose use my own cron script schedule at cron .
At my PHP script I prevent it from being called by browser, the I add in the follow shell script how many PHP services I want.
To keep everything secure, each PHP service needs a small token to run so, you will notice only if you have access to the source code.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# (c) 2016 por Marcello Fontolan
#
PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin
export PATH
LOCKFILE=/tmp/${0##*/}.lock

if [ ! -e $LOCKFILE ]
then
        touch $LOCKFILE
        cd ${0%/*}
        php movimentocopia.php token
        php pedidocopia.php token
        rm $LOCKFILE -f
else
        echo lock file detected.
fi
exit
```

At this moment I handle a different problem.
The provider connection and response time slow the amount of Text Message so I create a PID Queued Spool.

Something like this:

```
function execThis($c, $m) {
    $cmd = "nohup nice -n 10 /usr/bin/php -f execenvio.php {$c} {$m} >> /tmp/execenvio.log 2>&1 & echo $!";
    return intval(shell_exec($cmd));
}

while (count($pid) > NUMTASKS) {
    foreach ($pid as $kpid => $vpid) {
        $processState = NULL;
        exec('ps ' . $vpid, $processState);
        if (count($processState) < 2)
            unset($pid[$kpid]);
    }
}
$pid[] = execThis($vcliente->id, $vmensagem->id);
```

Well, the code above is part of my current system so you have only to figured out how adapt to your needs.

regards

Comment: i dont think this is answering the question asked

Comment: Sorry, I can say that Yes, it is a good pratice and Yes, it can increase traffic between PHP and database so the server must be good as your needs.
I prefer put also some example with a real running application that process about 100k Text Messages for month in a standard VPS.

Comment: now im really sure your not answering the question.

Comment: [Somebody has flagged your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18859837) as either "Not an Answer", or "Very Low Quality". Answers which are technically wrong should not be flagged; they should be downvoted or commented on. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1364007) post clearly says: "*Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer!*".