# Laravel Delayed Message Queueing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Referring to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#queueing-mail
How can i make mail queueing to send for a bulk users an email and keep gap between each email sent 1 minute.

```
foreach($user as $user){
Mail::later(60,'web.mail.NotifyUserExpiring', ['user'=> $Sub->user,'ExpiryDate' => $exp], function ($message) {
        $message->to($user->email);
        $message->subject('Services Renewal Reminder');


}
```

Comment: Try [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856000/320487

Comment: @HCK scheduling command will run the same controller each every minites that mean the foreach loop will start again and send to whole users , let say that i have 50 users that need to receive an reminder email . if send to user_id=1 then wait for 1 min then send to user_id=2 until the loop end .

Comment: mm you could create a job for each email to send, then set it up to run a job every X minutes. In case you need to run another group of emails to send, you could use a different queue.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses [Swiftmailer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#introduction) which has an [AntiFlood Plugin](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin).

So if you want to wait one minute after a mail has been send you could do it like that:

```
\Mail::getSwiftMailer()->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(1, 1));

foreach($user as $user){
   Mail::send(new Message($user));
}
```

If you want to pause for 30 seconds after 100 emails you would need to change the numbers in the first line to:

```
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));
```